# Cleaning ArrayCollections

Tags: actionscript-3

Initially I had ten arraycollections declared in a flex module, which I thought, were causing a memory leak. So I separated them in a single class, which I would clean using the "destroy" method I created inside it. Would this work?

I hate the question title excuse me. But I wouldn't write it like "Seducing the garbage collector"

```
        [Bindable]
        public class Cfd
        {
            private static var instance:Cfd = new Cfd();
            private var _cfds:ArrayCollection = new ArrayCollection();

            // Constructor
            public function Cfd(){
                if (instance) { throw new Error('Cannot create a new instance.  Must use Cfd.getInstance().') }
            }

            public static function getInstance():Cfd{
                return instance;
            }

            public function get cfds():ArrayCollection{
                return _cfds;
            }
            public function set cfds(value:ArrayCollection):void{
                _cfds = value;
            }

            public function destroy():void{
                if(_cfds != null){
                    _cfds.removeAll();
                }
                }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whenever you use Singletons like this, you pretty much guarantee a memory leak, because you're probably listening to the ArrayCollection  (and maybe items within it) from all over the place.  When you explicitly provide a reference to an object through a getter/setter pair, you can add the listener in the setter and removie it when the value is reset.

Check out http://www.developria.com/2010/08/rethinking-addeventlistener-an.html for more on what's happening.

For more on why you should avoid Singletons http://misko.hevery.com/2008/08/17/singletons-are-pathological-liars

Comment: I have to give it to you for warning me about singletons. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Just null the object should do it unless you have listeners attached to it.

```
cfds = null;
```

I have never seen [Bindable] used on the class itself, so not sure what you are trying to do there.

```
  package{
    public final class Cfd{
        private static var instance;

        private var _cfds:ArrayCollection = new ArrayCollection();

        public function Cfd(singletonEnforcer:MySingletonEnforcer){
            if (instance) { throw new Error('Cannot create a new instance.  Must use Cfd.getInstance().') }
        }

        public static function getInstance():Cfd{
          if (instance == null)
            instance = new MySingleton(new MySingletonEnforcer());
          return instance;
        }

        // don't see a real need for setter/getters here 
        public static function get cfds():ArrayCollection{
            return _cfds;
        }
        public static function set cfds(value:ArrayCollection):void{
            _cfds = value;
        }

        // I wouldn't even use a destroy on this class since it is a singleton.
        // just set the data to null Cfd.cfds = null
        public static function destroy():void{
            _cfds = null
        }
    }
  }

  //this is in Cfd.as but is outside the package block
  class MySingletonEnforcer {}
```

Comment: `[Bindable]` on class level makes all public properties of the class bindable. In this particular case its the exact same thing as putting it on the `cfds` property, since there is only one public property in the class.